# How to configure a custom resource type in a concourse pipeline?

Tags: concourse

I've already done a google search to find a way to setup a custom resource in concourse pipeline but the answers/documentation do not work.

Can someone provide a working example of custom resource type that is pulled from a local registry and used in a build plan?

For example, say I were to clone the git resource and slightly modify it and pushed it to my local registry.
The git resource image would be name: localhost:5000/local_git:latest

How would you be able to use this custom resource (local_git:latest) in a pipeline definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main settings to consider here when running a local registry:

1. Must use insecure_registries:

   `insecure_registries: ["my.local.registry:8080"]`
2. If you are running your registry in "localhost", you shouldn't use localhost as the address for your registry, if you do, the docker image will try to resolve to the localhost of the docker image instead of your local machine, in order to avoid this problem, use the IP address of your local machine. (DON'T use 127.0.0.1)

Comment: I also added the insecure_registries but it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you are running concourse and your docker registry on the same host right? If that is the case, you must use the host IP address + Port for the docker registry. You should not use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1". Did you try that?

Comment: that was the problem. I used a different local other than 127.0.0.1. Since you helped me out with this issue..is it ok to accept your answer? Thanks !

Comment: Good to hear that, if it helped you, you can accept my answer :)

Comment: You can review this page for more info about accepting answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom resource type in your pipeline under the `resource_types` key in the pipeline yml.

Eg:

```
resource_types:
  - name: custom-git
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: localhost:5000/local_git
```

An important note is that custom resource type images are fetched in a manner identical to using a base resource in your pipeline, so for your case of a private Docker registry, you will just need to configure the necessary `source:` on the `docker-image` resource (See the docs for the [docker-image-resource](https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource))

You can then use the type for resources as you would any of the base types:

```
resources:
  - name: some-custom-git-resource
    type: custom-git
    source: ...
```

Note the `type:` key of the resource matches the `name:` on the resource type.

Take a look at the Concourse Documentation for [Configuring Resource Types](http://concourse.ci/configuring-resource-types.html) for more information on how to use custom types in your pipeline.

Comment: Have you tried this configuration yourself? I tried this setup in my environment during the weekend but it did not work.