# Concourse docker registry could not find resource and discovering any new versions spinning

Tags: git, concourse

I'm a new to Concourse. I try to learn the tool going through docs and tutorials.
I have an issue with pulling docker image resource with concourse.
I have a docker repository that I can do regular docker pull image from.
On concourse I try the following:

```
resources:
- name: cloudnet-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: my-docker-repo.com/cloudnet
    tag: latest
```

when I push it to Concourse and run the pipeline even before it starts I get this statuses:

```
checking pipeline is not paused
checking job is not paused
discovering any new versions of cloudnet-image
discovering any new versions of cloudnet-workspace-repo
waiting for a suitable set of input versions
cloudnet-image - no versions available
checking max-in-flight is not reached
```

and "discovering any new versions of cloudnet-image" is spinning forever.

But if I try to configure repository from the tutorial it works OK

```
resources:
- name: cloudnet-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: concourse/docker-image-resource
```

What is wrong with my docker repository? Why Concourse could not find / agree to pull from it? What is the difference with the concourse/docker-image-resource?
How can I debug this kind of issues?

Thank you for your help!
Eden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your Registry is configured.

If you are using a Local, self-hosted, insecure Registry, you will need to use **"insecure_registries"**
You can find more information here:

- [Concourse Tasks](https://concourse.ci/running-tasks.html)
- [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46549320/2980510)

If your Registry is configured to be private, you will need to provide credentials:

```
image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: my-docker-repo.com/cloudnet
    insecure_registries: ["my-docker-repo.com"]
    username: MyUser
    password: MyPass
```

You can test if you need credentials by running this in your terminal:

```
docker pull my-docker-repo.com/cloudnet
```

If it prompts for credentials, then you need to provide them to Concourse. If this is the case make sure to provide them [Using ((parameters))](https://concourse.ci/fly-set-pipeline.html#parameters) like this:

pipeline.yml

```
...
username: ((RegistryUser))
password: ((RegistryPass))
...
```

credentials.yml

```
RegistryUser: MyUser
RegistryPass: MyPass
```

Command line

```
fly -t example set-pipeline --pipeline MyPipeline --config pipeline.yml --load-vars-from credentials.yml
```

**Note: NEVER commit credentials.yml to your source control.**

Comment: What if your registry is over HTTPS, but not password authenticated for pulling images? Would it also be a `insecure_registies`?